# I'm getting some of these prints in my console while running my application from Xcode 9.4 in my iPhone 7,8 with iOS 10,11

Tags: ios, google-maps, core-data, swift4.1, xcode9.4

the 'GoogleMaps' pods are all updated so where is this bug still shows
the Error is : CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0000000B-BDBC-0000-000B-0000FB00000B/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/StorageWithTileProto.omod'

Comment: this error is comes in the google maps place picker when i select the place all the ui freezes and nothing works

Comment: Please, not use the image for the text, edit your question with the error log text without the image.